# Combine two SQL Tables

Tags: sql, join, hive

Join both the tables and get first table data and second table data which is missing in Table1 by comparing on Col1 and Col11 I guess. As all the ID's (Col1 and Col11) should come together

**Table1**

```
Col1      Col2            Col3                  Col4      Col5            Col6 
1345653   330760137950    2012-07-09 21:40:29   1345653   331760137950    1341895229
1345653   110909316904    2012-07-09 21:29:06   1345653   111909316904    1341894546
1345653   221065796761    2012-07-09 19:31:48   1345653   221065796761    1341887518
```

**Table2**

```
Col11        Col22         Col33                  
1345653      330760137950   2012-07-09 21:40:29     
1345653      110909316904   2012-07-09 21:29:06     
1345653      221065796761   2012-07-09 19:31:48     
1345653    **150851771618**   2012-07-09 18:57:33
```

If you look above two tables data, last line in `Table2` means `Col22-150851771618` is missing in `Table1`. So I need to display `Table1` full data and last line from `Table2` as Col22 is missing in `Table1` by joining on `Col1` and `Col11`, like this below output.

```
1345653   330760137950    2012-07-09 21:40:29   1345653   331760137950    1341895229
1345653   110909316904    2012-07-09 21:29:06   1345653   111909316904    1341894546
1345653   221065796761    2012-07-09 19:31:48   1345653   221065796761    1341887518
1345653 **150851771618**  2012-07-09 18:57:33   NULL       NULL           NULL
```

How can I do this using `JOIN` by joining on `Col1` and `Col11`? I am having lot of confusion on this. Can anyone help me?

**Update:- Some more scenarios**

**Table1**

```
Col1            Col2            Col3                   Col4       Col5                Col6
1345653     330760137950    2012-07-09 21:40:29     1345653     331760137950        1341895229
1345653     110909316904    2012-07-09 21:29:06     1345653     111909316904        1341894546
1345653     221065796761    2012-07-09 19:31:48     1345653     221065796761        1341887518

704318001   320941581940    2012-07-09 14:44:48     704318001   321941581940        1341870288
```

**Table2**

```
Col11        Col22         Col33                   Col44   Col55   Col66
1345653      330760137950   2012-07-09 21:40:29     NULL    NULL    NULL
1345653      110909316904   2012-07-09 21:29:06     NULL    NULL    NULL
1345653      221065796761   2012-07-09 19:31:48     NULL    NULL    NULL
1345653    **150851771618**   2012-07-09 18:57:33   NULL    NULL    NULL

704318001  **290738585064**    2012-07-09 14:36:49     NULL    NULL    NULL
```

So Output should be like this- Meaning for this `1345653` ID, I need all record at same place and same with `704318001`. So if you look the output, all the `1345653` are together and all `704318001` are together.

```
1345653   330760137950    2012-07-09 21:40:29   1345653   331760137950    1341895229
1345653   110909316904    2012-07-09 21:29:06   1345653   111909316904    1341894546
1345653   221065796761    2012-07-09 19:31:48   1345653   221065796761    1341887518
1345653 **150851771618**  2012-07-09 18:57:33   NULL       NULL           NULL


704318001   320941581940    2012-07-09 14:44:48     704318001   321941581940        1341870288 
704318001  **290738585064**    2012-07-09 14:36:49     NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Basically, get the first table full and second table whose data is not there in Table1

Comment: What database and version of it you are using?

Comment: I am working with Hive and Hive supports SQL like syntax, but it has few limitations so it cannot use NOT EXISTS kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) should work..

But based on your data, I think you should be joining on `Col22` to `Col2`, since `Col1` and `Col11` don't have unique values, so I don't know how they are associated.

```
SELECT t2.Col11, t2.Col22, t2.Col33, t1.Col4, t1.Col5, t1.Col6
FROM 
    Table2 t2 LEFT JOIN
    Table1 t1 ON t1.Col2 = t2.Col22
```

Comment: Just updated the question with more scenarios and the output format. So do you think it will work that way?

Comment: I am not getting the actual output that I need. I have updated my question with more scenarios.

Comment: +1, You got the correct solution, but implementation slightly wrong -  You should be joining on `t1.Col1=t2.Col11` instead of column 2.

Comment: @Nevzz03 A warning: second scenario will fail because table2 does not contain two instances of `704318001`.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you need to add rows from table2 where you cannot find a match on first three columns in table1. You can combine [union all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29) and [exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) to that effect. If the database supports [except](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29) you might use it instead of exists.

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6
  from table1
union all
select Col11, Col22, Col33, null, null, null
  from table2
 where not exists (select null
                     from table1
                    where table1.col1 = table2.col11
                      and table1.col2 = table2.col22
                      and table1.col3 = table2.col33)
```

[UPDATE after clarification: if you can use union all and left join this SQL FIDDLE should help:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e19a/6)

```
select buyer_id, item_id, created_time, user_id, product_id, timestamps
  from TestingTable1
union all
select t2.buyer_id, t2.item_id, t2.created_time, null, null, null
  from TestingTable2 t2
  left join TestingTable1 t1
    on t1.buyer_id = t2.buyer_id
   and t1.item_id = t2.item_id
   -- remove this line if you identify duplicated record
   -- by buyer and item only
   and t1.created_time = t2.created_time
 where t1.buyer_id is null
```

Comment: Thanks Nikola for the comment, This is my SQL fiddle, in which I have created the schema. And I need Output like I have mentioned in my question. But I cannot use not exists because of database restricution. I need to use JOIN or UNION ALL somehow. [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e19a](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e19a)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, what exactly is the expected output - for example, do you need just a partial outer join or full outer join? assuming you need full outer join and this might do the trick (T-SQL syntax):

```
select
    coalesce(t1.col1, t1.col11),
    coalesce(t1.col2, t1.col22),
    coalesce(t1.col3, t1.col33),
    coalesce(t1.col4, t1.col44),
    coalesce(t1.col5, t1.col55),
    coalesce(t1.col6, t1.col66),
from
    Table1 t1
    full outer join Table2 t2 on t2.Col22 = t1.Col2
```

hope this is what you need. It should join all rows from both Tables on column Col2-Col22 and display for each column pair value from Table1 and if there is a null value it should display value from Table2

edit: you can not join the tables on Col1-Col11. That would in fact produce cartesian product on this example. But may be - depends on real meaning of the data - could be useful join on both Col1=Col11 and Col2=Col22

Comment: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e19a](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e19a) SQL Fiddle in which I have build my schema.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply -

```
SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

Else please make the question clearer.

Comment: If I do it like this, then I will be getting NULL infrom of the few Col11. I don't need that, I have clearly mentioned in my output.